# 16.04 Safely remove "ubuntu software" after installing appgrid?

Tags: 16.04, default, software-uninstall, alternative

I have installed appgrid. I am running on an Acer Cloudbook 14. Space is tight, but there are features that I don't want to lose. It  is lighter and seems to work faster with fewer bugs. Now I want to remove "Ubuntu Software" to make up for the space, if possible. Is this a bad idea? If not: Should I uninstall using appgrid, or terminal? I have not yet attempted removal. 16.04 is running great, by the way. It is very stable on this hardware.

Comment: I would say it's either a bad or neutral idea. Anyway, if you decide to uninstall it, how it's done doesn't matter. The GUI tools just run the same commands in the background. Keep in mind Ubuntu Software takes very little space so there's probably nothing to gain from removing it.

Comment: Update: I removed Ubuntu Software. Im running low on space. I need to buy a really good sd card so i can move my home folder there and make root bigger.  After thinking about everything, i went ahead and removed appgrid too. I dont ever hardly install anything by GUI, anyways. Your comment helped me make up my mind. I appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad idea to remove "Ubuntu Software." If you are comfortable using command line. Alternative installers upon failing may leave you in a position where you are forced to install or remove by terminal. I was only using Ubuntu Software or App Grid as a catalog of what i kept installed. These packages are not necessary for Ubuntu to function or update.

Comment: This self answer does not answer the question, the question is "how to remove ubuntu software" and all this says is "It is not a bad idea!", answers MUST answer the question, this is really a comment. It needs instructions to actually achive the goal outlined in the question.

Comment: My question isnt how. It was whether or not it was safe to do so.